# Issue with Inline Entity Form module

Tags: entities

I have a simple master-detail use-case with Customer as a master entity, and Estimate, a detail entity. In Estimate, I've created an Entity-Reference field called "Customer Name" that refers to the same column in the Customer entity.

But in Estimate entity, when I try to assign a widget type of "Inline entity form - Single value" to Customer Name, it threw the below error :-((

My objective is to provide an inline form so that user can add/edit customers while he is in the Estimate form itself. Please help.

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$nid in entity_metadata_no_hook_node_access() (line 619 of /home/prahlad/source/php/drupal7/sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/modules/callbacks.inc).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$vid in entity_metadata_no_hook_node_access() (line 620 of /home/prahlad/source/php/drupal7/sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/modules/callbacks.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in entity_metadata_no_hook_node_access() (line 620 of /home/prahlad/source/php/drupal7/sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/modules/callbacks.inc).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$nid in node_access() (line 2999 of /home/prahlad/source/php/drupal7/modules/node/node.module).
```

Comment: Well known problem, check project issue list:
https://drupal.org/comment/7409230#comment-7409230

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bugreport, for [already reported](https://drupal.org/comment/7409230#comment-7409230) bug. Bugreports are not allowed here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug which should be reported in the appropriate issue queue, if it is not already reported.